# Create a single JS function for all products in magento for add to cart using Ajax method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, magento

I have created a instant add to cart buttons successfully in Magento. I have done it using Forms and Java script i.e. each product displayed on the page has its own form and its won JavaScript function created on the form accordingly.

So, If I display 60 products in one page, it leads to 60forms and 60 js functions. Is there anyway where I can use a single JS for all the forms/products? ...I have tried and looked everywhere but unable to get a solution.

Here is the Form and JS:

```
 <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getId())?>"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>


   <button1  title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cartsd" onclick="productAddToCartForm<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getId())?>.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </form>
```

JS :

```
 var productAddToCartForm<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getId())?> = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getId())?>');

     productAddToCartForm<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getId())?>.submit = function(button) {

         if (this.validator.validate()) {
             var form = this.form;
             var e = null;
             var oldLabel;

             try {
                 this.form.request({
                     parameters: { adeptaajax:'true' },
                     onSuccess: function(transport){
                         var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                         var displayString = json.message;
                         if(json.success) {
                             jQuery("#topCartContent").load("page/ #element > *");
                             jQuery("#cartHeader1").load("page/ #element2 > *");
                         }
                         alert(displayString);
                     },
                     onFailure: function(transport){

                         alert("<?php echo $this->__('There has been a problem adding your product. Please try again later.'); ?>");
                     }
                 });
             } catch (e) {
             }
             if (e) {
                 throw e;
             }
         }
     }.bind(productAddToCartForm<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getId())?>);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you dont want to fire 60 requests and there is no checkout cart controller action which is able to add more than one product, you propably have to write your own addMultipleAction in a class extending `Mage_Checkout_CartController`.

There is a blog entry i found via a 2 second google search which seems to do exactly this:

http://www.danneh.org/2010/09/adding-multiple-products-to-the-cart-simultaneously-in-magento/

Comment: Thanks a lot Leiss for the reply, but the link which you gave is for adding multiple procucts at once. What I was looking for is to write a single JS function which all the 60 ADD to CART buttons can use. Right now I have 60 different JS fucntions - each button has its own JS function. My goal is to improve the Code. Please let me know if I missed anything